# Excel formula for min value if greater than negative number and less that positive

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need some help with a formula. I'm trying to work out the minimum value if greater than -365 but less that 365.

```
{=MIN(IF((E46:J46<365)*(E46:J46>-365),E46:J46))}
```

This is the formula I have so far, which is ignoring anything less that -365 and anything over 365.

It gives me the correct value if the minimum is less than 0 but anything greater than 0 is getting ignored, and the cell displays a 0.

For example,

**E** -42101
**F** 80
**G** -35
**H** 367
**I** "blank"
**J** "blank"

Then I will get -35 as my minimum value, if I delete this from the cell my minimum values turns to 0, when it should be 80.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Blank resolves to 0. You need to add one more boolean expression. One the checks if the cell is not blank.

Comment: Isempty or isnumber are the checks that you might need to get out the zeros that you get from blanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(myRng)),NA(),IF(myRng>365,NA(),IF(myRng<-365,NA(),myRng))),1)
```

entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

`MIN` does not ignore errors, but `AGGREGATE` can.

For a normally entered formula, provoked by @XORLX below:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(ISNUMBER(myRng)*(myRng>-365)*(myRng<365))*myRng,1)
```

or, more succinctly:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,myRng/(ISNUMBER(myRng)*(myRng>-365)*(myRng<365)),1)
```

To avoid returning `#NUM!` if there are no entries meeting the criteria, one solution is to use `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,myRng/(ISNUMBER(myRng)*(myRng<365)*(myRng>-365)),1),"")
```

Comment: AGGREGATE with CSE kind of defeats the point of that function, no?

Comment: @XORLX Yeah, but it works, and retains the value of zero

Comment: Sure, but with reciprocation we avoid the need for all the value_if_false clauses and also the need for CSE: =AGGREGATE(15,6,myRng/(ISNUMBER(myRng)*(myRng<365)*(myRng>-365)),1)

Comment: @XORLX I worked that out as you were posting it.  Thanks

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hi, both worked, but it is having the same issues as with my min. If there is no min that matches the criteria, the cell value is 0 i need it to be blank. Thanks

Comment: @atame Here the formula returns `#NUM!` if there is no min that matches the criteria.  What, exactly, is in your cells?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Since we're using AGGREGATE, we can do without the ISNUMBER test: =AGGREGATE(15,6,myRng/((myRng<365)*(myRng>-365)),1)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld. the 6 cells can contain any negative number or any positive number. Thanks

Comment: @atame No formulas?  Please provide a set of values that returns a `0` where there are no values meeting the requirement.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld. apologies I mixed that up with the Min formula, the aggregate it giving me a #NUM!, how can i get this to be blank. Thanks

Comment: @atame Just "wrap" it with an `IFERROR` formula

Comment: @XORLX  I don't think you can avoid the `ISNUMBER`.  `AGGREGATE` is evaluating the array produced by the division, and not the values in `myRng`.  So an empty cell will evaluate to `{TRUE,TRUE}`  and the division will evaluate to `0`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld. Thank you, worked great, out of curiosity, do you know how to resolve the displayed 0 for `{=MIN(IF((E46:J46<365)*(E46:J46>-365)*NOT(ISBLANK(E46:J46)),E46:J46))}`. Thanks

Comment: @atame You can first test all the cells to see if any meet the requirements:  `=IF(AND((myRng>=365)*(myRng<=-365)+ISBLANK(myRng)),"",MIN(IF((myRng<365)*(myRng>-365)*NOT(ISBLANK(myRng)),myRng)))`

Answer (score 2):

Like proposed in the comments, adding a check on whether the cell is blank or not should be sufficient to resolve your issue:

```
{=MIN(IF((E46:J46<365)*(E46:J46>-365)*(E46:J46<>""),E46:J46))}
```

(Entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

Comment: Thanks for that, pretty similar to what i worked out. =MIN(IF((E46:J46<365)*(E46:J46>-365)*NOT(ISBLANK(E46:J46)),E‌​46:J46)). My problem now is that if there is no minimum that meets the criteria it needs to display nothing, rather than the 0 it currently is. any thoughts?

Comment: Well, I tried several stuff but I couldn't find better than the aggregate() method raised by @Ron above... I'll keep on searching though

Comment: @atame you need to be careful with my solution: In the case you wrap this in an if() function to check if it returns 0, it'll work **but** if you actually have a _0_ in your list wich is the minimum valid value, it'll return _blank_ (instead of _0_)...

Answer (score 0):

With help from Ron Rosenfeld and Maxime Goguillon who have provided both great answers.

Ron Rosenfeld

```
{=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,E46:J46/((E46:J46)*(E46:J46>-365)*(E46:J46<365))*E46:J46,1),"")}
```

Maxime Goguillon

```
{=IF(MIN(IF((E46:J46<365)*(E46:J46>-365)*NOT(ISBLANK(E46:J46)),E46:J46))=0,"",MIN(IF((E46:J46<365)*(E46:J46>-365)*NOT(ISBLANK(E46:J46)),E46:J46)))}
```

Both of these work perfectly.

The help was much appreciated!!!!